# Dependent and independent variables

Tags: functions, derivatives, independence, classical-mechanics, continuous-variables

I am reading the Lagrangian viewpoint in Schwinger's book on electrodynamics [where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ESOp.png) he states that $\textbf{r}$ and $t$ are independent variables and the Lagrangian is given by:

$$L= \frac{m}{2}(\frac{d\textbf{r}}{dt})^2-V(\textbf{r},t)$$

But I am wondering wouldn't it be $\frac{d\textbf{r}}{dt}=0$ if they are independent. In his following derivation he writes something like $\textbf{r}(t)$ as I understand $\textbf{r}$ being the function of $t$. Please clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He's being imprecise. The Lagrangian is actually a function of $3$ sets of variables. $$L(\vec{r},\vec{v},t)$$

Here $\vec{v}$ has no relation whatsoever to $\vec{r}$ or $t$. They are fully independent variables.

Now, when you take a curve describes by $\vec{\gamma}(t)$ you can plug it in the lagrangian to get $$L \Big(\vec{\gamma}(t), \dfrac{d \vec{\gamma}(t)}{dt},t \Big)$$

And what he actually means by $\vec{r}(t)$ (which, again, I will denote by $\vec{\gamma}(t)$) being an independent variable is that it is an independent variable of the action functional:

$$S[\vec{\gamma}]=\int L \Big(\vec{\gamma}(t), \dfrac{d \vec{\gamma}(t)}{dt},t \Big) dt$$

So the action functional is a map from a space of curves to the reals. And the variable of the action functional is the family of curves upon which the functional depends.

So variations in $\vec{\gamma}(t)$ would induce variations in $S$. And by variations in $\vec{\gamma}(t)$ we mean just take $\delta \vec{\gamma}(t) = \epsilon \phi(t)$ for some small parameter $\epsilon$ (which eventually goes to zero) and arbitrary $\phi$ vanishing on the boundaries. It is in this sense that $t$ and $\vec{\gamma}(t)$ are independent: At each $t$ you can vary $\vec{\gamma}(t)$ by $\delta \vec{\gamma}(t) = \epsilon \phi(t)$. But it is an imprecise notion of "independence", since the only actual variable in the functional is the curve $\vec{\gamma}$.

The reason the author says that it is an independent variable of the Lagrangian is because when varying the functional you will vary the Lagrangian (by taking the limit inside the integral), hence you might as well just start varying the Lagrangian to see the variations in the functional. But the proper mathematical way to do it, is to vary the functional first which would induce variations in the Lagrangian.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! But I am having further question: will the end point variation ($\int_{t_1+\delta t_1}^{t_2+\delta t_2}$) affect the variation of the curve? What I mean is when we vary the action simultaneously w.r.t $r(t)$ and $t$(endpoints), will the $\delta \textbf{r}(t)$ be affected somehow by the endpoint variation. I suppose it won't since we are considering the $\delta \textbf{r}(t)$ at each $t$, is this reasoning correct?

Comment: It will not affect it in the sense that $dt$ will induce some change $\delta \vec{r}(t)$, but you will get additional terms in your variation. If you vary the action with respect to both then you will still get $\delta \vec{r} = \epsilon \phi$ for some $\phi$ regardless whether you induced a variation $dt$ or not. However the $dt$ will increase the limits of your integration, hence increasing the domain upon which the action will feel the presence of  $\phi$. This still doesn't mean that one will affect the other directly, though. This can all be formalized precisely.

Comment: If you define the action as a map from the space of curves (defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$), cross $\mathbb{R}^2$ then notice if you take a variation $\epsilon \phi$, then increasing/decreasing the limits of integration will not affect the variation $\epsilon \phi$. It's still $\epsilon \phi$ but the action will feel more of its presence if you get what I mean.